# add an image to an UIAlertBuilder

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uialertview

I have an UIAlert builder and i would like to add an image between the title and the button. This is my code:

```
UIAlertView *pull = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"pull_wire", nil)
                                    message:nil
                                    delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"continue_text", nil)
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"cable.png"]];

[pull addSubview:imageView];
[pull show];
```

But the image is shown on top of the UIAlertView.

With @yunas solution:

[image]

Could be the image is too big?

Resizing the image:

[image]

how can I get it inside the UIAlert?

Comment: you need to apply transformation.

Comment: @yunas, could you explain it a litte bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *pull = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"pull_wire", nil)
                                    message:nil
                                    delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"continue_text", nil)
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

[pull show];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"cable.png"]];
    CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 80); // set the origin here
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(90,40);//ANY SIZE that you want, but remember if you want the alertview to be big in size you need to apply transformation on the pull (ALERTVIEW)
[imageView setFrame:frame];
[pull addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I have the same result, edited my post with the result

Comment: alright you need to change the width and height of the imageView accordingly.

Comment: kindly join me here for more discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27759/ios-discussion

Comment: I got it adding @\n\n\n as @eddierockz said

Answer (score 2):

```
UIAlertView *pull = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"pull_wire", nil)
                                message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"continue_text", nil)
                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
```